# Lightweight battery replacement for GPS

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, gps

I've been using a 12V, 7Ah sealed lead acid battery for my GPS equipment, but need something lighter.

The battery(s) will be charged daily.

Does anyone have suggestions for a battery or battery combinations that could achieve this?

Comment: The most advanced battery technology today is the LiPo. Look for it.

Comment: Is the lipo more for high draw applications such as RC helicopters etc.?

Comment: The weight and reliability are most important. The batteries will be in a backpack and may get hot so will need to be stable.

Comment: Gps reciever and a radio. Max draw won't exceed 1.2A.

Comment: I'd avoid LiPos in hot backpacks as they have a nasty tendency to, well... explode in a ball of flames if provoked. LiFePO4 (or phosphate) cells would be the go, their energy density is a bit lower than Li-Ion and LiPo, but they have long life cycles and won't catch fire even if punctured, a lot of EVs use Lithium phosphate cells for this reason. More costly than lead acid but they'll weight *much* less.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the power draw of your GPS equipment (are you using just a receiver or an entire computer system to analyze the data?) but lipo would be a good choice. A lipo can do high currents for long times without heating up, however it is not good with high heat environments.

You don't need a high C rate lipo, 20C at 5 or 10 amp hours will be plenty and much lighter.